# trouble with HTML code for adding audio to a link when clicked

Tags: html

I'm writing a code for a web page in HTML 5 and I can't seem to get my audio file to play when a link is clicked.  It will play the audio when you click the back button on the browser but not when the link is clicked.

Here is the section of code that I'm having trouble on:

```
  <audio id="hit" src="audio/hit.mp3" preload="hit"></audio>

  <a href="Index.html" onclick="document.getElementById('hit').play()">Home</a>
  <a href="Lessons.html" onclick="document.getElementById('hit').play()">Lessons and Camps</a>
  <a href="Staff.html" onclick="document.getElementById('hit').play()">Staff</a>
  <a href="Error.html" onclick="document.getElementById('hit').play()">Online Store</a>
  <a href="Contact.html" onclick="document.getElementById('hit').play()">Contact</a>
```

I tried adding a semicolon to each link after the () but that didn't help.  I also tried adding a preload="auto" to the  tag but that didn't help either.  I have a first code page in the course that I am taking that I copied to code from directly and that one is working fine so I'm not sure why this isn't doing the same.

I didn't know if is something that I have to define outside of a div or not, but I tried moving it and it still only works when the back button is clicked.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

When you click those links, they perform your `onclick` event, but the link is also followed. You can stop the navigation like this (keeping things as similar as possible to your original HTML).

```
<a href="Index.html" onclick="document.getElementById('hit').play(); return false;">Home</a>
```

Comment: That gets the sound to play when the link is clicked but then it won't navigate to that page, is there a way to have it do both?

Comment: Not with this design... if you navigate, the audio will stop. Tell me a bit about what you are aiming to do - for example, play the sound for 5 seconds and then navigate, or play the sound after navigation?

Comment: I'm just trying to make a 2 second mp3 sound of a baseball bat hitting a ball play when a link is clicked.  I have a homework assignment a few weeks ago where it worked just fine and I'm using the same audio file and the same code but for some reason it's not working now.